# Sympy: Extract the two functions solutions of a homogeneous second order linear ODE

Tags: python, sympy, differential-equations

I have a homogeneous second-order ODE, whose general solution is `ur(r) = C1*u1(r) + C2*u2(r)`.

How can I get `u1(r)` and `u2(r)` as separate functions by setting `(C1=1, C2=0)` and `(C1=0, C2=1)`, respectively?

This is what I tried (and other variants as well)

```
import IPython.display as disp
import sympy as sym
sym.init_printing(latex_mode='equation')

r = sym.symbols('r', real=True, positive=True)
ur = sym.Function('ur', real=True)
def Naxp(ur):
    return r**2 * sym.diff(ur(r), r, 2) + r * sym.diff(ur(r), r) - ur(r)
Naxp_ur = Naxp(ur)
EqNaxpur = sym.Eq(Naxp_ur)
#print('Radial ODE:')
#display(Naxp_ur)
ur_sol = sym.dsolve(Naxp_ur, ur(r))
ur_sol1 = ur_sol.rhs
#display(sym.Eq(ur(r), ur_sol1))

# I still have to find how to extract the two basis functions
#u1 = sym.Function('u1', real=True)
C1, C2 = sym.symbols('C1, C2', real=True)
u1 = ur_sol1.subs([(C1, 1), (C2, 0)])
print(u1)
```

and I always get a result as if `subs` were ignored

```
C1/r + C2*r
```

Comment: Can you share a more complete script with all the imports and variable definitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sympy isn't recognizing the equality between the constants it generated and the ones you generated. This seems to be due to setting your constants with `real=True`. Remove that and the code works.

```py
C1, C2 = sym.symbols("C1 C2")
print(ur_sol1.subs({C1:1, C2:0}))  # 1/r
print(ur_sol1.subs({C1:0, C2:1}))  # r
```

There's probably a way to extract the constants and avoid defining them yourself, but I'm not sure the best way to do that. It could involve `ur_sol1.free_symbols`, but that also returns `r`. Edit: The [sympy documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/guides/solving/solve-ode.html#work-with-arbitrary-constants) seems to recommend creating the variables yourself, but there is probably still a better way.

Also, you might want to consider setting the initial conditions for your ODE to get a particular solution.

Comment: This works. 
Setting the initial conditions for the ODE to get a particular solution is not useful in my case, as I would have to know the solution in advance to set the right values that correspond to {C1:1, C2:0} and {C1:0, C2:1}.

Comment: Would you know why I have to remove `real=True` to get the correct result?

Comment: If you create variables with different assumptions then sympy won't recognize them as the same. Sympy generates those constants without any assumptions, so you have to define them the same way.

Comment: That's the page I linked in my answer.